# how to integrate Facebook Instant Articles with October CMS?

Tags: octobercms, facebook-instant-articles

I want to apply Facebook instant article with my own website. My website was built by using October CMS. And I don't know how to do? Could anyone guide me step by step where to start it?

Comment: Reading "Documentation" is the ideal way to start.

Comment: its document doesn't talked about FB Feed.

Comment: It wont talk about that.. you need to utilize and follow the coding stuff to be able to achieve this stuff.

Comment: I found this plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/inkrement-facebookfeed,

Comment: I hope it works after hosting.

Comment: There you go .. (y)

Comment: I get this message "could not authorize request. please check your facebook AppID, page id and secret!"